# Как сделать так чтобы при клике создавался новый div block javascript

Tags: javascript

Учу javascript, хочу сделать мини-игру в браузере, есть корабль который должен стрелять пулями, хочу чтобы при каждом клике создавался новый div block( пуля ),
но не могу это сделать так как, при каждом клике он просто заменяет старый div на новый...

help me!(

вот код:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container")
var bullet = document.getElementById("bullet")
var numberBullet = 0;
var speed = 0;
var check = 0;

document.onclick = function() {
//создание пули
container.innerHTML = "<div id='bullet' class = 'bullet' </div>"
var bullet = document.getElementById("bullet")

if(numberBullet > 10) {
    numberBullet = 0 
}

//координаты пули
var x = event.clientX
var y = event.clientY
bullet.style.left = x + 'px';
bullet.style.top = y + 'px';


var timer = setInterval(move,50)
function move() {
    speed -= 10
    bullet.style.top = y + speed + 'px'
    console.log(speed)

    if(speed < -500) {
        clearInterval(timer)
        speed = 0
    }
}

//удаление пули
setTimeout(rem,2600)
function rem() {
    bullet.remove();
}

//console.log(x,y)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ship = document.querySelector('.ship');

ship.addEventListener('click', shoot);

function shoot() {
  var bullet = document.createElement('div');
  bullet.classList.add('bullet');

  var shipCoordinates = ship.getBoundingClientRect();
  var bulletPosLeft = shipCoordinates.right;
  var bulletPosTop = shipCoordinates.top + shipCoordinates.height / 2;

  bullet.style.left = bulletPosLeft + 'px';
  bullet.style.top = bulletPosTop + 'px';

  document.body.append(bullet);
  eraseBullet(bullet);
}

function eraseBullet(bullet) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    bullet.remove();
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ship {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 89% 56%, 100% 63%, 67% 100%, 50% 100%, 9% 99%, 0 69%, 28% 55%);
}

.bullet {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: piu-piu 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes piu-piu {
  to {
    transform: translateX(1000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ship"></div>
```